# Python - invalid syntax for loop

Tags: python, loops

I'm having a bit of trouble with a for loop. I get SyntaxEror: invalid syntax line 2 when I try to run the code below:

```
myList = [[3,5,7,10,47,5,11],[6,23,26,38,39,4,11],[11,27,33,39,44,2,10],[15,19,32,43,45,1,2]]
for x in myList:
    if x == [3,5,7,10,47,5,11]:
            print 'match'
    else:
        print 'no match'
```

I have used for loops to do loops such as the one below:

```
animals = ['dog','bear','cat','lion','zebra']
animals.sort()
for x in animals:
    if x == 'dog':
        print 'match'
    else:
        print ''
```

and they always seem to work. I have a feeling that maybe the syntax is wrong on the myList variable. I've tried using '' and declaring int but no luck.

The program should assign all the sublists as x and then see if x matches the list i've set and simply tell me whether it's a match or not.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
  File "match.py", line 2
    for x in myList:
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have an indentation error on *line 3*, but that is probably just a posting error. Otherwise there is no error here. Please *include* the actual error message in your post, instead of having us guess.

Comment: The code you're posting shouldn't be giving that error.  Please double check that the code on this page is the **exact** code you're running.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indent the print statement:

```
if x == [3,5,7,10,47,5,11]:
    print 'match'
```

Comment: Which is line 3 at the very least.

Comment: It looks like you might be mixing spaces and tabs in your code.

Comment: Got it working. I had a comment # in my code which was stopping the final brace ] from being included in the code. Thank you - regards.

Comment: No worries; glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new, valid line *above* the `for` loop, like a `print` statement.

Get a syntax error there now? Then your list is not properly closed, you are missing a closing bracket on your *first* line. Check if all your opening `{`, `[`, and `(` braces are matched with a corresponding `}`, `]` or `)`.